# ANGULAR2 ROUTES are not bootsrapped

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-directives, angular2-services

The new router (3.0.0) provides the `provideRouter` function which takes an array argument of the type `RouterConfig`...

The official developer guide provides a tutorial by bootstrapping a `const`. Example:

`export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
   provideRouter(routes)
];`

I just want to bootstrap it as a `class`

`-->` `client.ts` the bootstrap file

```
...
import {APP_ROUTER} from './app/app.routes';
...

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, APP_ROUTER, ...]);
```

`-->` `app.route.ts` the routing file

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { somecomponents }; 

@Injectable()
export class APP_ROUTER {

  constructor(
    RouterConfig: RouterConfig

  ) {   
    this.ROUTE_prov = [provideRouter(this.prov)];

  }
    public ROUTE_prov;
    public prov : RouterConfig = [
    { path: '/', component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutPageComponent },
    { path: 'landing', component: LandingPageComponent },
    { path: 'pp/:nickName', component: PersonalPageComponent },
    { path: 'carlos', component: CarlosPageComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ];
}
```

And I get this error... The routes are not loaded : [image]

Answer (score 0):

router-config.ts

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';


export const APP_ROUTES : RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', component: AppComponent},
    // more paths
];

export const APP_ROUTE_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES)  
];
```

main.ts

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ...]);
```

Comment: like I said : `I just want to bootstrap it as a class` not as a `const` or `var`

Answer (score 0):

following your comment try this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { somecomponents }; 

@Injectable()
export class APP_ROUTER {

  constructor(
  ) {   
    this.ROUTE_prov = [provideRouter(this.prov)];

  }
    public ROUTE_prov;
    public prov : RouterConfig = [
    { path: '/', component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutPageComponent },
    { path: 'landing', component: LandingPageComponent },
    { path: 'pp/:nickName', component: PersonalPageComponent },
    { path: 'carlos', component: CarlosPageComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ];
}
```

and then in your main.ts :

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, RouterConfig, APP_ROUTER, ...]);
```

Comment: hmm, I tried, it doesn't work, anyways the problem doesn't lie in the `RouterConfig`...
I think is the `provideRouter`...

Comment: Try this: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, RouterConfig, APP_ROUTER, provideRouter(APP_ROUTER.prov)]);`

Comment: thanks dude I'll edit your answer...
I made a static function which returns an array of routes :) !